# Why does Maven not see JavaFX graphics module (while Eclipse does)

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-module

I have a multi module Maven project, and one of the modules uses JavaFX. While everything compiles fine in Eclipse, doing a

> mvn clean compile

returns this error

```
package javafx.scene.robot does not exist
```

It seems like maven cannot see the `javafx.graphics` module that contains the `javafx.scene.robot` (but Eclipse does see it, because it gives no compile errors). How can I get Maven to compile this code?

I have created a mini version of my application that reproduces this. These are the files:

Main pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.eddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>   <!-- JDK Version -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>mod1</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Module pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.eddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Launch.java

```
package nl.eddy.mod1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.robot.Robot;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Launch extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        new Robot();
    }

}
```

module-info.java

```
module nl.eddy.mod1 {

    requires javafx.controls;
//  requires javafx.graphics; uncommenting this does not change maven's message
}
```

Output of mvn clean compile

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/egr/eclipse-workspace/demo/mod1/src/main/java/nl/eddy/mod1/Launch.java:[4,26] package javafx.scene.robot does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/egr/eclipse-workspace/demo/mod1/src/main/java/nl/eddy/mod1/Launch.java:[15,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Robot
  location: class nl.eddy.mod1.Launch
[INFO] 2 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] demo ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.368 s]
[INFO] mod1 ............................................... FAILURE [  2.541 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.161 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-11T13:08:56+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project mod1: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/egr/eclipse-workspace/demo/mod1/src/main/java/nl/eddy/mod1/Launch.java:[4,26] package javafx.scene.robot does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/egr/eclipse-workspace/demo/mod1/src/main/java/nl/eddy/mod1/Launch.java:[15,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Robot
[ERROR]   location: class nl.eddy.mod1.Launch
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Details of compiler from log of `mvn -X compile`

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: C:\apps\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 12.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows server 2012 r2", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: What JDK are you using when you compile? (Run `mvn -X compile` to find out)

Comment: @JoséPereda I haved added the start of the ```mvn -X compile``` output to the post above.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Make sure you don't have any other JDK in the `%PATH%`, as Maven will pick that instead. Also you can try adding to the compiler plugin configuration: `<executable>/path/to/javac</executable><fork>true</fork>`, where the path is points to that JDK 12.0.2 above

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks for pointing me to the compiler plugin configuration. I just had to change the release to 12, it was 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling went fine as soon as I changed the maven-compiler-plugin release element to value 12 instead of 11. I.e., the same value as the compiler actually running Maven. Many thanks to @JosePereda, see comments.